# Multiple Inputs/Checkboxes jQuery Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-pagination

I'm not sure where the best place to start or the best way to achieve this is but I currently have 4 multiple sliders (two handles within on slider), one input box, another 4 checkboxes and a dropdown and have 1000+ results being returned, I want to whenever something is changed, to update the results via jQuery and paginate it.

So far, I have the results return in multiple formats, json, html, but am not sure the best way to achieve this live (onchange of anything) search with pagination.

Any suggestions or if you can point me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Anyone else have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you want to display these 1000+ results.. I hope not in a dropdown as that would seriously upset most users. :D

Have a look at [jquery datatables](http://datatables.net/).

Comment: No it wouldn't be in a dropdown. :P It would be in a table, and the pagination isn't too much of a problem. -- The multiple checkboxes, dropdown, sliders - live search is the issue I'm having..

Comment: datatables can do all the pagination you need. You either give it all the data or write some server-side pagination for which data-tables will tell you what it needs, just check out their docs

Comment: then you need an input that updates the results, which you then display wherever?

Comment: I have multiple inputs (term, a few sliders, and a few checkboxes) that on change of any of them need to request a jQuery search, now I know how to retrieve and display the results via jQuery, I'm just stuck at the method on how to monitor the multiple inputs for any change and then pass them to the jQuery $get..

Comment: inputs have the .change() event ;)